# Issues with saving json in Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, json

I am currently having issues trying to save to a .json file and reload it later. The program seems to save somewhat properly, but I get an error when attempting to reload it later on. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong and have attempted to fix it for roughly 30 minutes now. Please note that I am a novice to Python and would appreciate simplified responses.

This is the json file (which will never be the same).

```
{"stat.playOneMinute":44,"stat.leaveGame":1,"stat.timeSinceDeath":44,"achievement.exploreAllBiomes":{"value":0,"progress":["ForestHills"]}}
```

This is the error I get when attempting to reload the json file later:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oiest\Desktop\Code\Minecraft Editor\v1.0.0\MCEditor.py", line 91, in <module>
    MainMenu()
  File "C:\Users\oiest\Desktop\Code\Minecraft Editor\v1.0.0\MCEditor.py", line 26, in MainMenu
    EditWorld()
  File "C:\Users\oiest\Desktop\Code\Minecraft Editor\v1.0.0\MCEditor.py", line 51, in EditWorld
    EditProcess()
  File "C:\Users\oiest\Desktop\Code\Minecraft Editor\v1.0.0\MCEditor.py", line 69, in EditProcess
    print('stat.timeSinceDeath is currently ' + str(data['stat.timeSinceDeath']))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

This is the code that causes the error:

```
    with open(stats_path + json_file, "r+") as jsonFile:
        data = json.load(jsonFile)
        print(data)
        print('')

        print('What do you wish to edit?')
        print('stat.timeSinceDeath')
        user_input = input('Edit Stat: ')
        if user_input == 'stat.timeSinceDeath':
            print('stat.timeSinceDeath is currently ' + str(data['stat.timeSinceDeath']))
            print('')
            user_input = int(input('New Stat: '))





            data['stat.timeSinceDeath'] = user_input
            jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
            jsonFile.seek(0)  # rewind
            jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data['stat.timeSinceDeath']))
            jsonFile.truncate()
            print(data['stat.timeSinceDeath'])
```

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the small possible **complete** program that still demonstrates the problem. (10-20 lines is usually sufficient.) Copy-paste that **entire** short program into your question. See [mcve] and [ask] for more information.

Comment: @Robᵩ I've updated the code.

Comment: Your code is still incomplete. Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Robᵩ That is the code that demonstrates the problem..

Comment: No, it relies on an external file, which we do not have.

Comment: @kindall Okay, I updated it now. That is the only external file it uses is that json file which it may never use again because you can decide which file you wish to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that what's in your data file is just an integer. How did it get that way? Well, the problem is here:

```
jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
jsonFile.seek(0)  # rewind
jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data['stat.timeSinceDeath']))
jsonFile.truncate()
```

You write out the new file, then rewind and write out *just the timeSinceDeath* over top of it. Which is an integer. So the next time you run the script, the JSON data is just the integer and so you get the error about subscripting an integer.

You can even see this very clearly from your `print(data)` call. (Good idea, adding a `print` to help debug. But it's even better to actually pay attention to it!)

To avoid this, don't overwrite your data file with just an integer. Take those two middle lines out. And put the original JSON back in the file.

Comment: How do you put JSON back into the original file?

Comment: Close. You still need to rewind the file before you overwrite it.

Comment: I actually found that just removing the third line solved my issue. I still needed the second line, but my program seems to be functioning now.